# Conditional select between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, between

I have a table and would like to find minimum and maximum values of price. 
I would like to get minimal price from action_table when current date between "from" and "to".

```
from        to          action_price  price
2015-04-02  2015-08-02  20            25
2015-04-02  2015-04-20  0             30
2015-04-03  2015-04-21  0             40
```

So from the table above I need: **min->20** (because current date between "from"/"to") and **max->40**

I have tried something like that, but don't work as expected:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN curdate() BETWEEN from AND to THEN MAX(action_price) ELSE MAX(price) END AS max,
CASE WHEN curdate() BETWEEN from AND to THEN MIN(action_price) ELSE MIN(price) END AS min
FROM `table`;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want minumum and maximum of these values:

> <del>25</del> 20, 30, 40

You simply need to wrap the case statement inside the aggregate functions instead of other way round:

```sql
SELECT
MIN(CASE WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN action_price ELSE price END) AS `min`,
MAX(CASE WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN action_price ELSE price END) AS `max`
FROM action_table;
```

```
+------+------+
| min  | max  |
+------+------+
|   20 |   40 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a "HAVING" statement will work here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4653c/4

Comment: Is it possible also to get max price in one request?

Comment: the only solution i have in mind right now is to use a ugly subselect... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff6107/7

Comment: I have 4 columns in my database. But yours have 3?!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for getting the minimum value in `action_price`.

```
SELECT MIN(action_price) 
FROM yourdb 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') > from 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') < to;
```

I tried this on fiddle, and worked, I just renamed 'from' and 'to' column since they are reserved words on MySQL.

As for the **MAX** value, I don't know what you exactly want, what would be the condition to get that **MAX value?** Same as for **MIN?** Anyway, let me know and I'll improve my answer with the correspond query for it.